# nextJS deep dynamic routing

Tags: routes, next.js

While I'm developing with NextJS, I have a question. 
To Use dynamic routing, we write file like [id].js 
When my directory structure is like this: 
pages 
 ㄴ area 
 
   ㄴ [area].js ,br/>

page example is like 'area/texas' or 'area/newyork'

I want to double dynamic routing like 'area/texas/houston' or 'area/texas/dallas' 
(page/area/region, area and region can change)
But I don't know how to make file structure 
I tried a few way, I failed :-( 

Let me know, how to make structure!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rename [area].js to [...area].js