# How do I name page templates for nested dynamic routing in Next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, dynamic-routing

I'm trying to achieve a dynamic routing structure, using Prismic within my Next.js app. Essentially, I have a page, `mysite.com/landing-page` for example, that I'm able to route to within my `[uid]` template, using `{ uid } = params` in my `getServerSideProps` function. However, I want to allow users to visit that same page via a subdirectory, such as `mysite.com/sacramento-ca/landing-page`. The research that I've done seems to indicate that I can create a content relationship within my Prismic repository that specifies the location from which the page could also be referenced (`sacramento-ca` being the example here), and then reference those in my query, and pass that to the page template. However, I can't figure out how to make that happen.

My `pages` directory is structured like this:

```
├── [uid]
│   └── index.tsx
├── index.tsx
├── products
│   └── [uid].tsx
├── projects
│   └── index.tsx
├── promos
│   ├── [id].tsx
│   └── index.tsx
└── sitemap
    └── index.tsx
```

..and overall this works just fine for top level pages. But 1. how can I query the `category` in `getServerSideProps` and how would I name and nest the page templates? I read this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61698338/nextjs-deep-dynamic-routing) as well, and that seems like it's on the right track, but I'm not sure how to make it happen. Here is the code for my `[uid]` template as well, in case that's helpful.

```
import React from 'react';

import { SEO } from 'components/seo/SEO';
import { SliceZone } from 'components/slice-zone/SliceZone';

import { client, queryWithProducts } from '../../lib/prismic';

export const Page = ({ document }: any) => {
  const slices = document;
  if (!slices) return null;

  const { meta_title, meta_description, meta_keywords, social_image } = document;

  return (
    <>
      <SEO
        title={meta_title}
        description={meta_description}
        keywords={meta_keywords}
        banner={social_image.url}
      />
      <SliceZone slices={slices} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Page;

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params, query }: any) => {
  console.log(query)
  const { uid } = params;
  const { data: document } = await client.getByUID('landing', uid, queryWithProducts);

  return {
    props: {
      document,
    },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, you can use a [dynamic catch-all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation).

You'll need to rename your folder to `[...uid]`, which will make `params.uid` return and array rather than a string.

```js
// [...uid]/index.tsx

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params, query }: any) => {
    const { uid } = params; 
    // When navigating to /sacramento-ca/landing-page `uid` will 
    // be an array containing ['sacramento-ca', 'landing-page']

    // Add logic to retrieve data based on array values

    return {
        props: {
            document,
        },
    };
};
```

Comment: Okay, I've gotten the basics of this working. The only thing that I'm struggling with is that I can't figure out how to parse the array values to get the data from `Prismic`. Essentially, `sacramento-ca/interior-doors` works, but when I visit just `interior-doors` I get an error, saying that my `Prismic` client expects a string literal.

Comment: Since the location, `sacramento-ca`, is optional you should adapt the code to support that - you could check for the `uid` array length and query the data from Prismic differently based on it.

Comment: What I wrote for now is something akin to this: `const parsed = _.isArray(uid) ? uid[1] : uid[0]` and then I pass `parsed` to my Prismic client. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Actually, `uid` will always be an array. You need to check whether to pass the second element or the first based on the number of items it contains.